# Supremum over $x\in[0,1]$ of $\lvert x -y\rvert$

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization

I have encountered the following optimization : find the supremum over $x\in[0,1]$ of $\lvert x-y\rvert$ with $y\in[0,1]$. While the geometric point of view is essential here to seek a solution I have not found a consistent way to do this and I would like to know if there is one.

Here is my solution :

We have the distance of two points in $[0,1]$. In order to get the supremum over $x$ we distinguish two cases :

1. $y\leq \frac{1}{2}$ : for this case, the supremum is $1 -y$
2. $y>\frac{1}{2}$ : for this case, the supremum is $y$

I am not very happy with this solution because it is only based on my geometric intuition.

I would like to know if there is a more « analytical view » to see this problem and solve it ?

The main reason is that I am pretty sure that for problem of this form a little more complicated (not just $x-y$ inside the absolue value or with a less simple domain) the geometric intuition will not be enough.

Thank you !

Comment: One way you could do this is argue that $|x - y|$ is a convex function in $x$ (prove it using Jensen's inequality; triangle inequality will help). Convex real functions over compact intervals achieve their maxima at an endpoint of the interval, so you really have $\max_{x \in [0, 1]} |x - y| = \max\{|0 - y|, |1 - y|\}$.

Comment: Another explanation could be as follows. Assume that the  point $y$ is sort of dangerous. You want to be located  as far from $y$ as possible but within $[0,1].$  Clearly you should go either to $0$ or to $1$. Then you choose the greater value $y$ or $1-y.$